# Need assistance determining which Bing Maps API license needed

Tags: bing-maps

A company sells products/services, any customer that enters into an agreement to purchase those products/services, can access the company's website.  Once logged in, the customer can see on a map, the location of their offices/branches by address.  We are estimating the page accessing the API requests at 100 / day.

Google requires a premium plan to use their geocoding API, I confirmed this with a Google sales rep. However I am struggling to determine what plan is appropriate if Bing's map API was used, and unfortunately the online quote request I submitted, the email was bounced back to me, saying inbox was full lol !

Could someone assist me in determine which license I would need?  We do not have any Azure subscriptions at this time, and we are not tracking via GPS, only address.  Here is the link i am referencing: https://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the appropriate license should be addressed to the vendor directly. We're not MS Bing licensing support. Questions about use of the API are appropriate here; questions about license selection are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please contact the Bing Maps licensing team at maplic@microsoft.com and they will assist you in determining the best way to license this type of application.